# associating a boolean variable with a link with agents from another breed

Tags: netlogo

I am having a problem associating a boolean variable with a link with agents from another breed.
My code, however, is not working.

```
turtles-own [manipulated?]
breed [families family]
breed [developers developer]

to setup
  clear-all
  crt 10
  [
    set breed families
   ]

  crt 5 [
    set breed developers
   ]

  ask turtles [
  create-link-with one-of other turtles
    let manipulable link-neighbors with [ breed = developers]
    ifelse manipulable [set manipulated? TRUE] [set manipulated? FALSE]
  ] 
  reset-ticks
end
```

Comment: when you say your code is "not working", do you mean an error message, unexpected behavior, or what? if the former, please provide the message. if the latter, please describe the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're after here- are you trying to get the turtles that link with a developer to set their `manipulated?` value to true? If so, maybe something like this will work- try replacing your `ifelse manipulable...` statement with:

```
set manipulated? ifelse-value any? manipulable [ true ] [ false ]
```

If that's not quite what you're looking for, could you go into a little more detail?

**Edit:** As per Seth Tisue's comment, the code above can be improved to:

```
set manipulated? any? manipulable
```

Comment: @SethTisue Excellent, thank you for the tip. Please feel free to post that as an answer- in the interim I will edit my answer to point out your improvement.